# Some hints on how to prove these two questions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was told to draw out a picture (Venn Diagram) and then to use them to prove that

$P(A) \geq  P(A \cap B)$

$P(A) \leq  P(A \cup B)$

I have no idea where to begin and the pictures aren't helping me at all. Can I get a helpful hint / idea of where I should begin. Thanks

Comment: probabilities cannot be negative. Any event in $A$ is also in $A\cup B$ so we must have $p(A)\le p(A\cup B)$. Similarly, any event in $A\cap B$ is in $A$ so we must have $p(A\cap B)\le p(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you drawing the diagram? Draw a rectangle. This is your sample space. Draw two circles in it so they overlap. These are your $A$ and $B$. The overlap part is $A\cap B$. Now shade $A, B, A\cap B$ in 3 different colors or 3 different shades. It should be apparent from the diagram now that the shaded area under $A\cap B$ is a part of the shaded area under $A$, and so $P(A)\geq P(A\cap B)$. Can you do the other part now?

Comment: I didn't have the rectangle. That's a good thing to add on. I did draw the circles like that. Thank you that really helped. It is so simple when you put it that way.

Comment: Well the rectangle isn't essential to proving the problem, as you can see here, but I've been taught as a convention to use it. :)

Comment: The rectangle helps you visualise probability as a measure of the proportion of the rectangle enclosed by the loops.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $A\subseteq C$ then $P(A)\leq P(C)$, write $C=A\cup (C\setminus A)$ and remark that $A\cap (C\setminus A)=\emptyset$ (and draw).